# Use bootstrap's tooltip with complex html on a table cell

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show complex HTML tooltip whenever I hover a table cell(let's call it the `outer table`).
The complex HTML tooltip is another table(let's call it the `inner table`).
the actual inner table is being built at runtime, but for the example, i will use a static HTML.
I have set the outer table cells like this:

```
<td data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-placement="bottom"></td>
```

and the mouseover event :

```
$(#myTable td).on("mouseover", function () {

  $(this).attr("title", "<table><tr><td>some tooltip</td></tr></table>")
  $(this).tooltip({html: true});

}
```

The tooltip popups but without parsing the text as HTML.
what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing tooltip of every mouseover Better to initialize once Look at following code snipset.

Instead of of this

```
$(this).tooltip({html: true});
```

To

```
$('td[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({html: true});
```

& Your HTML markup should be

```
<td data-toggle="tooltip" title="<table><tr><td>some tooltip</td></tr></table>" data-placement="bottom"></td>
```

In case of static html content above code work.

In case of **dynamic** content below code useful

```
$('td[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({html: true});
```

need to initializing tooltip after appending dynamic data.

& need to change title attribute for dynamic content.

```
$(document).on('mouseover','#myTable td', function () {
  var dyanmicContent = 'Hello World';
  $(this).attr("title", "<table><tr><td>" + dyanmicContent + "</td></tr></table>")
}
```

Comment: But the dynamic data is appended on each "mouseover" event so if I want the initialize the tooltip after setting the content, it has to be inside the "mouseover" event. I tried your solution but still didn't work....

Comment: If anyone can suggest even using a nice jquery plugin that can deal with complex html tooltips it would also be ok